# Prove: If $\limsup a_n<\infty$ then $|a_n|<M$

Tags: analysis

Is there an issue for this problem? for example, if $a_n=-n$, then $\limsup a_n=-\infty<\infty$, but this sequence is not bounded.

Comment: Yes, as written your example works as a counter example. Maybe the source of the problem had previously written that $a_n\geq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as it is, the property is false since you can give a counterexample.

However, you can slightly modify your problem and show that $ \limsup a_n < \infty $ implies $a_n < M$.

Let $b_n = \sup_{p \geq n} a_p$. By definition, $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{p \geq n} a_p = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n $.

As $ \limsup a_n < \infty$, the sequence $(b_n)$ is bounded from above. Let $M$ be such that $b_n < M$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Then

$$ \forall n,\quad  \sup_{p \geq n} a_p < M.$$
In particular, for $n = 0, \quad \sup_{p \geq 0} a_p < M$. Then $a_n \leq M$.

As noted by QC_QAOA, you solve your problem if you add the assumption that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded from below.

Comment: Thank you, and when the problem wrote $\limsup a_n <\infty$, it actually means $\limsup a_n$ exists and equals to some infinite number, right? Since it exists, equivalently, $\lim b_n$ exists and equals some finite number, so $b_n$ is bounded.

Comment: In fact, for every sequence $(a_n)$, $\limsup a_n$ exists in $\bar{\mathbf{R}} = [-\infty, +\infty]$.   Your assumption $\limsup a_n  < \infty $ ensures that it's not $+\infty$   (Be careful, in your comment you wrote some "infinite" number instead of "finite"